# Black Holes and the Multiverse

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, big-bang, singularities, multiverse

Are there any peer-reviewed theories which explore the idea that black holes in our universe may spawn other universes - or that our universe came from a black-hole-like event in another universe?

If so, what are the names of those theories and their authors? If not, why not?

This is due to the observation (perhaps superficial) that black holes seem to share similarities with the beginnings of the universe - a singularity, a change in the relative dynamics of the forces, and a heavy warping of space and time.

Comment: The curvature of the early universe was, as far as we can tell... flat. Black holes are "classical" solutions, so it's not clear what you mean by "breakdown of classical physics". No change in the dynamics of quantum physics has ever been observed or is postulated by models for quantum gravity. As far as I can tell every one of your points is based on a misconception, so far.

Comment: To reopen this question (v1) please define what is meant by "other universes in other dimensions".

Comment: I have deleted the phrase 'in other dimensions'. What I meant by this is a universe that is somehow 'cut off' and re-inflated from the point of a black hole.

Comment: A singularity is not a physical fact but a failure of the theory. Even so, the mathematical type of singularity in the cosmological solution would be very different from that of a black hole solution. "extremely high" is a human expression that has no physical meaning. The energy density in the nuclei of your body is "extremely high". Can you feel it?

Comment: The geometry of the Big Bang is very different to the singularity at the centre of a black hole. However there have been suggestions that black holes can be linked to other universes. This relies on patching together a Schwarzschild and de Sitter geometry in a rather ad hoc and physically unmotivated way.  see for example [Has the universe we live in started as a black hole that is imploding?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136262/has-the-universe-we-live-in-started-as-a-black-hole-that-is-imploding).

Comment: @CuriousOne, by classical I mean newtonian concepts of gravity within a black hole.  By quantum dynamics I mean the forces at a quantum level change in their relative strength (i.e. gravity becomes strong).

Comment: Also [Maximum curvature in a black hole](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128473/maximum-curvature-in-a-black-hole) and [How does the friedmon solution to Einstein's equations resolve paradox of bounded infinities?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123595/how-does-the-friedmon-solution-to-einsteins-equations-resolve-paradox-of-bounde). Most of would regard this as highly speculative to say the least.

Comment: "classical" doesn't mean Newtonian in physics. The running of "forces" in quantum field theory is a necessary part of the theory that has nothing to do with your question. Whether gravity ever becomes strong at "short" distances is highly questionable. There are plenty of possible models in which it never does. In general, the entire idea of the Planck scale is highly suspect and there is not a single experimental confirmation for it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: re your first comment, the curvature of a spacelike slice of the early universe appears to be flat. The whole universe is most certainly not flat, has never been and if dark energy is real never will be.

Comment: @JohnRennie: That's what I understood the OP was talking about. Whether we can ever determine the entire geometry of the universe sounds questionable to me... that would require us to have an experimental crystal ball with infinite time horizon, which is a bit of stretch for my imagination. I welcome the correction, though.

Comment: @JohnRennie, thankyou, that is what I was looking for - Lee Smolin's idea's regarding 'cosmological natural selection'. A really intriguing concept.

Comment: @Amphibio: an intriguing concept but a daft one. The patching together of different metrics is fine mathematically but has no physical basis.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I think that, by analogy to darwinian selection, the idea that there would be a greater propensity for black holes to form over successive generations of universes doesn't make sense. After all, plants do not evolve just to make more and bigger seeds - they evolve to better adapt to their environmental relationships, whilst maintaining and enhancing their ability for reproduction. What this might mean in the context of an imagined multiverse, is of course, anybody's guess :)

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed for being unclear.... the question was in the last two paragraphs, neatly rounded off by question marks