# Infinite number of universes? Black holes are guilty?

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, black-holes, astrophysics, big-bang

I was thinking, if the space is infinite, what if there are infinite number of spaces, inside our universe? I mean, everyone knows that black holes exist, but nobody knows what happens when you get sucked in.

Therefore, I believe that inside the black holes there must be some kind of molecule compression which bursts out inside the black hole after molecules get overcrowded and can't compress anymore. That could be actually how Big Bang happened. Furthermore, after the bursting, something has to happen. Probably after billions of years new black holes inside the former black hole start forming, while the former one expires.

The Big Bang should happen right after the black hole itself collapses, actually expires, because black hole finds itself in position where there is nothing so close that it can suck in, therefore it cannot gain mass anymore. In other words, if nothing were to enter the black hole, Hawking Radiation would allow it to expire.

The best of all is that every universe has multiple black holes, which means even more universes to come alive. The other universe, the one that you're not in, is now another dimension.

Based on my beliefs and some research, I believe that we are the outcome of some another universe. Now, my question is, is my belief plausible, based on on facts that I may not know.

On the other hand, if black holes aren't guilty for the Big Bang,may it be that our scales are to small? That the cosmic egg was actually so big that at a specific moment it collapsed and made itself over again? What if Big Bang is yet to happen and that we are part of it?

Comment: I liked this question because I do not think it quite deserves a downarrow (it had 1), however, as I stated, this is a site for serious questions about physics, not fun conjectures.

Comment: The scenario you describe has been studied, and indeed it's the basis behind [Lee Smolin's theory of cosmological selection](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Life-Cosmos-Lee-Smolin/dp/0195126645), though you should note that few physicists take this proposal seriously. The physics behind this arises from Markov's papers that I reference in my answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123595/how-does-the-friedmon-solution-to-einsteins-equations-resolve-paradox-of-bounde).

Comment: Imagine that the energy does "squirt" out of black holes to form new universes. That would cause a decrease of energy/mass in our universe, which as far as I know, does not happen. With Hawking Radiation eventually even the most massive black holes will "evaporate" back into our own universe and disappear. Black holes are not alive so don't need a constant influx of energy to exist. The fact of the matter is that we are unable to directly observe what happens beyond the event horizon of a black hole leading to wild hypotheses, so we need to use computer modelling to guess as best we can.

Answer (score 1):

We do not know if the universe is closed or open, so space could very well be infinite. However, that does not mean that there is an infinite amount of space in anything. Such a conclusion does not quite make much sense in terms of a logical,mathematical (or even philosophical) argument.

Take Zeno's paradox for instance: The paradox states(in summary) that a value can be divided an infinite number of times, so if this happens forever, does the value ever actually reach zero? And practically speaking, yes, we can sum a geometric series to say that it does converge to a number eventually. Just because something can be divided an infinite number of times, doesn't mean that what you have is considered to be infinite. If you have a wooden plank that is 2 meters long, you could come up with a measurement even smaller than a Plank length to describe it, but in the end, practically speaking, you still have a board that is 2 meters long.

The rest of your argument has no physical basis whatsoever, so I cannot believe that you actually think this to be a logical theory. It is simply a conjecture based upon a misunderstanding of the subject. However, this does not mean that it is wrong to have thoughts like this, in fact I encourage you to do so. But when going with your question on a legitimate physics website, you may not get the answer that you had hoped for.